# Why on page load iframe shows loading video and how can i fix it?

Tags: html, iframe, tailwind-css

When i visit the page the iframe shows loading player which look weird. I want to fix it. Is there a way to fix it ?

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

```
<section class="relative table w-full">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="grid md:grid-cols-12 grid-cols-1 items-center mt-10 gap-[30px]">
                    <div class="md:col-span-12">
                        <iframe class="w-full aspect-video " src="../src/assets/video/rubyonrails.mp4"></iframe>
                    </div><!--end col-->
                </div><!--end grid-->
            </div><!--end container-->
        </section>
```

Comment: Can you at least explain what does before and after means? Before what? After what? Ideally you should post minimal reproducable for your issue (for example using codepen)

Comment: @zerdox these are SC. Before loading the video and after loading the video.

Comment: as you can see in before. It shows me small size video player.

Comment: Oh.. I guess this is because browser doesn't know dimensions of your video before it was fetched. You can try to set width and height using html attributes for example. This is best practice for images and videos

Comment: @zerdox  Can you please edit the code for better understanding